# JQuery foreach, select multiple spans and add to Div

Tags: jquery, html, each

I am trying to loop through each `<span>` element individually and add it with some individual html, with my js even with foreach, it is always alerting all the elements as one entity. Any suggestions on where it is going wrong here...

```
$("#testDiv").html("");
$("#main span b").each(function () {
     alert($('#main span b').text());
     $("#testDiv").append($("<span/>", {
         class: 'adkeys',
         html: $('#main span b').text() + "<a class='anch'>"
     }));
});
```

For my following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LEe7B/

Answer (score 1):

Use the `this` keyword inside the loop, not the selector again

```
$("#testDiv").html("");

$("#main span b").each(function () {
     alert($(this).text());

     $("#testDiv").append($("<span/>", {
         'class' : 'adkeys',
         html    : "<a class='anch'>" + $(this).text() + "</a>"
     }));

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/LEe7B/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use $(this) inside the loop body or write as in the following...

```
$('yourselector').each(function(index,value){
 alert($(value).text());
});
```